# Is the p-value dependent on n in case of paired student t-test?

Tags: t-test, sample-size, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have a dataset where we believe there are a bunch of infected and uninfected subjects (total being 15). There are two ways to categorise these subjects into infected/ uninfected: 1. categorise 10 subjects as infected and the remaining 5 as uninfected, 2. Divide the data into 7 infected and 8 uninfected.

We have some measures taken using these subjects at 2 time points (TP-1 and TP-2) and would like to compare the group mean (each group being a time point of measure) using paired t-test. I performed multiple tests, since we have multiple measures and FDR corrected using BH correction.

In the end, I observe that when I divide the samples into 10 infected and 5 uninfected, the difference between group mean (TP-1 vs TP-2) is significant in uninfected and not significant in infected after FDR correction. When the sample is divided into 7 infected and 8 uninfected, the difference between group mean (TP-1 vs TP-2) is not significant in both cases after FDR correction. However, the group mean difference is significant in uninfected when we look at uncorrected p-values (p-val < 0.05).

My question: is the difference between FDR corrected outcome and uncorrected outcome dependent on sample size (5 in one case and 8 in the other)?

Comment: Please say what FDR correction method you are using.

Comment: @BruceET: Sorry that I did not mention it earlier. It was Benjamini-Hochberg method.

Comment: Seems you've got a useful Answer from @EdM (+1).

Answer (score 1):

At least two common methods for dealing with multiple comparisons, the [Holm-Bonferroni method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method) for controlling family-wise error rate and the [Benjamini-Hochberg method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini%E2%80%93Hochberg_procedure) for controlling false-discovery rate, only use the uncorrected *p*-values and the number of hypotheses being considered for correction. If the sample size affects the uncorrected *p*-values then it can affect the correction. Otherwise, at least for those methods, there is no explicit consideration of sample size.

That said, I'm a bit concerned about how you are trying to distinguish your infected from uninfected groups. In particular, if you are using your TP-1 values as part of making that group distinction then there's a risk that the paired differences you are evaluating are inherently correlated with the group assignments. Even if that's not the case, you are probably better off trying to use a single linear model to evaluate all the cases together rather than doing these multiple t-tests, and it's probably dangerous to use this type of test to determine which of your group-assignment methods is best.

Comment: That was really useful. Thanks. Would a linear mixed effect model be more suitable, since the measures could be correlated?

Comment: @swatkats yes, that would probably be more suitable. Use the actual values at the 2 time points, not the differences, as the outcome variables. Include time point (TP1 vs TP2) as a fixed effect along with the "infected/not" category (probably with an interaction between them), with a random intercept for individuals. Be careful that your process of assigning the "infected" status doesn't somehow bias your analysis.

Comment: @swatkats with only 15 cases and thus only 30 observations you might not have enough data to evaluate an interaction term, as I had previously suggested. Overfitting is always a risk with a small data set.